# I set BrowserMobProxy & Desired Capability in selenium and create jar,jar i using in soapUI to automate,But soapui not able to load "https:// Url"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, groovy, soapui

**This is my selenium code which i am using as a jar in soapui** 
*But soapui not able to load https url using this code so can any one give me the solution*
**Below is my code:**

```
 import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxy
import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer
import net.lightbody.bmp.client.ClientUtil

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy
    // Setting Chrome Driver System Property
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe path")

        def response = null

        // Set Request Filter parameters
        def requestFilter = new RequestFilterImplementation()
        requestFilter.setHeaderValue(headerdata)

        // Initializing BrowserMobProxy
        BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer()
        proxy.start()
        proxy.addRequestFilter(requestFilter)

        // Initializing Selenium Proxy with the BrowserMobProxy
        Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy)

        // Setting the Desired Capability
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy)
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true)
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_WEB_STORAGE, false)


        // Initializing the Web Driver
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities)
        driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

**I want to pass url that belongs to https**

```
driver.get(URL.toString())
```

> if url is http then it's working fine through soapui but not in https
>
> I am passing url which is working in eclipse but not in soapui

Comment: Please enter the code as text with `code formatting` into the question and not as image.

Comment: I added code kindly check.

Comment: @MarkusEgle did you have any solution on that. I'm trying various way but not able to solve this,if you looking to this it's may helpful for me.